# Не работает очень простой слайдер на js

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть слайдер на 4 картинки.Каждая занимает 100% блока.При нажатии next она сдвигается в лево на 100% и появляется новая.

```js
var left = 0;
document.getElementById("next").onclick = sliderLeft;
function sliderLeft() {
  var polosa = document.getElementById("polosa");
  var max_lenght = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
  left = left - 100;
  if (left < max_lenght.length) {
    left = 0;
  }
  /*
   if (left <= -400) {
    left = 0;
  }
  */
  polosa.style.left = left + "%";
}
```

```css
body{
 display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
#slider {
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.arrows {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#polosa {
  position: relative;
  display: inherit;
  transition: 1s ease;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="polosa">
  <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534106474077-f9e9c6f5a47c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=93e4a52103a10a38beffb1c30bed41ba&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
 <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534076355207-1717511180ba?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=dac3b914c452ddd9c6c51e1828ac0a76&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
 <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534083264897-aeabfc7daf8a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d40d4da633c570324291ec2e6e5bd4f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
<img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534083152091-df439a43a2b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3bf58d027c1a0fbd9b92cd1de830438f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrows">
  <button id="prev">prev</button>
  <button id="next">next</button>
</div>
```

В общем по началу когда у меня пролистались все картинки у меня была простая проверка `if (left<= -400){left=0}` и оно моталось к первой картинке.Но допустим каждый раз я буду добавлять картинку я не хочу каждый раз в коде менять числа (с 400 на 500 с 500 на 600 и т.д.)Я попытался сделать переменную в которой будут все картинки и в проверке прописать переменная.lenght `if (left < max_lenght.length) {
    left = 0;
  }`

Но у меня не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы изначально сравнивали количество пикселей в left с -400, а в итоге стали зачем-то сравнивать количество изображений с left.
Исправленный вариант:

```js
var left = 0;
document.getElementById("next").onclick = sliderLeft;
function sliderLeft() {
  var polosa = document.getElementById("polosa");
  var max_lenght = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
  left = left - 100;
  if (left <= (max_lenght.length*-100)) {
    left = 0;
  }
  /*
   if (left <= -400) {
    left = 0;
  }
  */
  polosa.style.left = left + "%";
}
```

```css
body{
 display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
#slider {
  border: 3px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.arrows {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#polosa {
  position: relative;
  display: inherit;
  transition: 1s ease;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="polosa">
  <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534106474077-f9e9c6f5a47c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=93e4a52103a10a38beffb1c30bed41ba&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
 <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534076355207-1717511180ba?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=dac3b914c452ddd9c6c51e1828ac0a76&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
 <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534083264897-aeabfc7daf8a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d40d4da633c570324291ec2e6e5bd4f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
<img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534083152091-df439a43a2b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3bf58d027c1a0fbd9b92cd1de830438f&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrows">
  <button id="prev">prev</button>
  <button id="next">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: я подозревал что я наломал дров с длинной и количеством .Спасибо тебе